# Swift unit test for a trailing closure in a function

Tags: swift, unit-testing, closures, xctest

Function with a Trailing closure:

```
code(for: "Hello world") {

func hello(_ name: String? = nil) -> String {
      return "Hello, \(name ?? "World")!"
}
}
```

Unit tests for HelloWorld:

```
public class HelloWorldUnitTests: XCTestCase {

func testHello() {

      XCTAssertEqual(hello(), "Hello, World!")
  }
  static var allTests: [(String, (HelloWorldUnitTests) -> () throws -> Void)] {
      return [
          ("testHello", testHello),
      ]
```

If I make hello() as public without closure, tests were passed.I want to make it work with trailing closure within code function. Please help me with this

Comment: "I want to make it work with trailing closure within code function" ***Why?***

Comment: See [The XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: It sounds like you want to use expectations: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/asynchronous_tests_and_expectations/testing_asynchronous_operations_with_expectations